# When should I say the phrase ビールのおかわりお願いします?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

When should I say this phrase?

> **ビールのおかわり**お願いします。
>   *Bīru no o kawari onegaishimasu.*

I couldn't figure out the meaning.  My main source of confusion is that I've never seen this sentence construction: [noun]のおかわり.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「ビールのおかわりお願{ねが}いします。」

＝

> 「ビールのおかわり**を**お願いします。」

「おかわり」 means "another helping", "refill", etc.

So, 「ビールのおかわり」 just means "another beer".

Therefore, you say:

> 「[Name of food/drink item] + （を） + お願いします。」

Whenever you have finished your current serving and you are wanting to have another.

Comment: Or simply 生｛なま｝(=draft)をください ;)

Comment: What if one says 'Okawari no biiru' ?